# Edit original question to reflect update in the duplicate?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, editing-help

Yesterday, user asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29867870/precision-of-calculations) without given the relevant code. Another user gave an answer giving good advice.

Today, the first user posted [another (almost identical) question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29900177/how-to-obtain-fortrans-precision-in-matlab), but this time giving the code in question. With the code, I was possible to identify the mistake, identifying the question as a duplicate. I then decided to post the answer on the original question, but there it is incomprehensible without the code.

What is the protocol here? Should I edit the original question to reflect the additional information? Should copy the answer? Should I move it?

I already asked the OP to add the code to the original question (which others have done as well).

Comment: How about close voting the first question as a duplicate of the better one?

Comment: @rene Can't do that any more... I used my vote to close as off-topic yesterday - the code is/was missing. If the user edited their post, I would be happy to retract that vote. Also, the question is already closed by a gold-badge user!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think closing the first question as a duplicate of the newer question with more details seems the best approach.